# How to add new line Character ( \n ) in message resource bundle in JSF1.2

Tags: jsf

In my sample JSF application am using rich:dataTable in page to display data.

I have 2 header to display  value in   rich:dataTable like following

```
--------------------------------
| UserDetails | EmpoyeeDetails |
--------------------------------
```

In  message  resource bundle  file having key and value like

usrDet = UserDetails 
empDet = EmpoyeeDetails

I need to display like User  in one line and Details in next line of that particular header

```
----------------------
|  User   |  Empoyee |
| Details |  Details |
---------------------
```

How to add new line character in message bundle between words? I tried by adding Hexadecimal code, Numerical Code for \n like 
 , \u000A but its not 
working for me! Any Idea?

Answer (score 22):

JSF generates HTML. Newlines in HTML are **not** represented by the `\n` character, but by the `<br>` element.

In order to have the HTML client to interpret `\n` too, you need to throw in CSS `white-space: pre` or `pre-wrap`:

```
key = Lorem ipsum.\nDolor sit amet.
```

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.key}" style="white-space: pre-wrap" />
```

Alternatively, use `<br>` instead and have JSF unescape it. E.g.

```
key = Lorem ipsum.<br/>Dolor sit amet.
```

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.key}" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the steps outlined here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-insert-a-new-line-in-resource-bundle-messages-java/

Basically, you use the StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String str) static method.