# Error adding new line in Spring.message property

Tags: java, javascript, spring

Hi there I´m using spring properties to localization of my text, so I have something like

```
     my.property.test=This is my propery
```

Then in my Javascript I get the literal using spring.message

```
  var test = <spring:message code="my.property.test"/>
```

With this scenario everything works like a charm. 'But' if I try to add a new line on the text as here:

```
      my.property.test=This is my \npropery 
      or
      my.property.test=This is my \n\propery
```

Browser always return me this error

```
      SyntaxError: missing } after property list


    onCriteriaNotOpenProcedureQualificationWorksBellMessage : ''This is my 
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Any suggestion

**Solved**

Since is a message source, I have to use

```
 <br/>
```

Comment: [I hope this answer would be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210672/11464928)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the '\' ?

```
  my.property.test=This is \\n my property
```

Comment: but '\' not add a new line. I need a new line

Comment: Found the solution. Since is message source have to use <br/>